# Does polymorphism allow to override all the methods of its superclass in subclass?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Please explain this with an example.!

It is not mandatory for a subclass to be overriding all the methods from the superclass.
It provides the option to override methods, but it's not a requirement.

Polymorphism allows a subclass to provide a specific implementation for a method defined in its superclass. This means that you can have a method in a superclass that is not overridden in a subclass. In such cases, the subclass will inherit and use the implementation from the superclass.
Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: There are plenty of examples in [java.lang](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/package-summary.html#class-summary).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is not mandatory for a subclass to override all the methods from the superclass. It is optional and depends on the design and functionality of the subclass. Polymorphism allows a subclass to provide a specific implementation for a method defined in its superclass, but it does not force it to do so. If a subclass does not override a method, it will inherit and use the implementation from the superclass by default.

For example, suppose we have a superclass called Animal that has a method called makeSound() that prints "The animal makes a sound". We can create a subclass called Dog that overrides this method and prints "The dog barks". We can also create another subclass called Cat that does not override this method and inherits it from Animal. If we create objects of these subclasses and call their makeSound() methods, we will get different outputs:

```
// Create an object of Dog class
Dog dog = new Dog();

// Call the makeSound() method of Dog class
dog.makeSound(); // The dog barks

// Create an object of Cat class
Cat cat = new Cat();

// Call the makeSound() method of Cat class
cat.makeSound(); // The animal makes a sound
```

As you can see, the Dog class provides a specific implementation for the makeSound() method, while the Cat class uses the general implementation from the Animal class. This is an example of polymorphism and inheritance in Java.

Comment: ChatGPT is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

This is language-specific. In Java, methods are 'overridable' by default, so unless declared otherwise, a child class can override all methods.

You can, however, declare methods final, in which case [they can't be overwritten by a child class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).

Other languages work differently. In C#, for example, you have to explicitly declare a method with the [virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) keyword. Unless you do so, a child class can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a superclass called Vehicle with a method startEngine():

```
public class Vehicle {
    public void startEngine() {
        System.out.println("Engine started.");
    }
}
```

Now, let's create a subclass called Car that inherits from Vehicle. In this case, we can choose whether or not to override the startEngine() method:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Car is moving.");
    }
}
```

If we don't override the startEngine() method in the Car class, it will inherit the implementation from the Vehicle class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        Car car = new Car();

        vehicle.startEngine();  // Output: Engine started.
        car.startEngine();      // Output: Engine started.
    }
}
```

As shown in the example, when we create an instance of the Car class and call startEngine() on it, it uses the implementation from the Vehicle class because we didn't override it.However, if we want to provide a specific implementation for the startEngine() method in the Car subclass, we can do so by overriding it:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public void startEngine() {
        System.out.println("Car engine started.");
    }

    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Car is moving.");
    }
}
```

Now, when we call startEngine() on a Car instance, it uses the overridden method.